# Flutter Add-to-app Can I add half screened flutter widget in an iOS view controller

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, widget, flutter-widget

I am referring to the below in Flutter documentation.

As of Flutter v1.12, add-to-app is supported for the basic scenario of integrating one full-screen Flutter instance at a time per app.

Can I add a half screened flutter widget in an iOS view controller and on clicking it, it should go to full screened flutter screen. Does the above limitation affects this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

We can use flutter widget as part of view controller similar to adding flutter screen to existing app.